# Are custom shortcuts broken by migrating from 3.x to 4.0?

Tags: shortcut, brushes

In Blender 3.5 I made B the brush shortcut in Grease Pencil Draw mode, when I updated to Blender 4.0 the shortcut no longer works and starts a 'box selection' operation. The E shortcut for the eraser tool still works, though.

So far I've tried reinstalling, resetting all configurations and (obviously) tried re-binding the shortcut.

Anyone else getting this problem?

Comment: Some of the keymapping has changed with version 4 and Blender have provided a video detailing the changes [here](https://youtu.be/QhYplmY1gtU) which might help.

Answer (score 0):

If one key is bound to multiple operators, only one will run and the rest will be ignored. In your situation, I think you just need to remove or change the <kbd>B</kbd> key binding for the operators you don't want. To list the <kbd>B</kbd> key bindings, in the preference:

1. Click the *Keymap* button.
2. Click the *Key-Binding* button.
3. Type *b* in the search box.

Now, all you have to do is remove or change the bindings listed under *Grease Pencil*. If you want to target one mode only, you don't have to change the rest.

[image: Keymap]